# How to save np.append become column just like this pic

Tags: python, numpy

```
fitur.append(meanList)
fitur.append(rata_rataList)
np.savetxt('variance/fitur.csv',fitur, newline='n')
```

my values written into rows, but i want to write into CSV in table form, i want:

```
MeanList  rata_rataList
value 1| value 2
value a| value b
```

thank you!

Comment: Look a `np.array(fitur)`.  That's what is actually saved.  Spend some time reading about the deliimiter and `fmt` parameters.

Comment: The subject line mentions `np.append` but the code uses the list append.  Those are not the same thing; don't confuse them!

Answer (score 1):

you can use to save your data in CSV or excel.xlsx if you want:

```
fitur.append(meanList)
fitur.append(rata_rataList)
fitur.to_csv('name_of_excel.csv')
```

OR

```
fitur.append(meanList)
fitur.append(rata_rataList)
fitur.to_excel('name_of_excel.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `delimiter` and `header`:

```
np.savetxt('variance/fitur.csv',fitur,header='meanList {:^2s}'.format('rata_rataList'),delimiter="|")
```